# Как установить telebot

Tags: python, telebot, anaconda

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли установить библиотеку Telebot через Conda?

```
conda search pytelegrambotapi
```

не находит эту библиотеку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чем проблема активировать необходимый енвайрмент и установить библиотеку с помощью pip?

```
conda activate my_env
pip install pytelegrambotapi
conda deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install pytelegrambotapi
pip install pytelegrambotapi

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, поясните, чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от того, который был дан три года назад.